# How to take only first 3 numbers from a long decimal number

Tags: java, android

I want to find the IP class.The IP address example is 198.160.12.0 (this will be entered in EditText)
I want to take only first 3 numbers, how can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

You can split your string

```
String string = "198.160.12.0";
String[] parts = string.split(".");

String part1 =  parts[0] // first part
String part2 =  parts[1] // second part
String part3 =  parts[2] // third part
```

Answer (score 0):

> public String substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex) Parameters: Here
>   is the detail of parameters:
>
> beginIndex -- the begin index, inclusive.
>
> endIndex -- the end index, exclusive.

Use System.out.println(Str.substring(0, 3));

Comment: Nope. The OP want the first three parts seperately `198` , `160` and `12`

Answer (score 0):

You can do either of the following:

```
String str = "198.160.12.0";

//first alternative
String[] split = str.split("\\.");
System.out.println(split[0]);

//second alternative        
String splitStr = str.substring(0, str.indexOf('.'));
System.out.println(splitStr);
```